# Ubuntu 20.04 image given by Ornangepi giving error while running RVIZ

Tags: 20.04, ros, orangepi

I am trying to run Rviz on orangepi 5B on the operating system Ubuntu focal 20.04 that I downloaded from there website [OS Download site link][1], when I am trying to run Rviz it's not running and giving me the following error. However , I have ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and RVIZ works perfectly on that.

```
[ INFO] [1700970498.693212054]: compiled against Qt version 5.12.8
[ INFO] [1700970498.693466676]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: rockchip
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: rockchip
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 148 (Unknown), sequence: 185, resource id: 0, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 20
```

Any help would be much appreciated
[1]: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xhP1KeW_hL5Ka4nDuwBa8N40U8BN0AC9

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, you'll need to install the appropriate graphics driver for your Orange Pi 5B. Unfortunately, there is no official driver available from Ubuntu for this chipset. However, there is an unofficial driver that you can install manually.

Here are the steps on how to install the unofficial Rockchip graphics driver on your Orange Pi 5B:

1. Download the Rockchip graphics driver from the following link: https://opensource.rock-chips.com/wiki_Graphics
2. Extract the downloaded driver files to a directory on your Orange Pi 5B. For example, you can extract them to `/opt/rockchip-graphics`.
3. Install the following driver dependencies using the following command:

`sudo apt-get install mesa-common mesa-utils libdrm-dev libegl-dev libgles2-dev libmali-dev libmali-rk3399-dev`

4. Change to the Rockchip graphics driver directory:

`cd /opt/rockchip-graphics`

run the following command to build the driver:

`./build.sh`

5. Once the driver is built, run the following command to install it:

`sudo make install`

After installing the driver, reboot your Orange Pi 5B for the changes to take effect.